# Separate numbers in math expression

Tags: java, regex

I have a math expression stored as a String:

```
String math = "12+3=15";
```

I want to separate the string into the following:

- int num1   (The first number, 12)
- int num2   (The second number, 3)
- String operator  (+)
- int answer  (The answer, 15)

(num1 and num2 can be digits between 0-20, and operator can be either +,-,*,/)

What is the easiest way to achieve this? I was thinking about regular expressions, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: It this the only format you have? Or you expressions can be more complex like `12+3+(2-3)=14`?

Comment: does your expression ALWAYS consist of two operands and exactly one result?

Comment: Yes, this is the only format I have. The expressions can be:
2+3=5       6/2=3        12*3=36         22-20=2       and so on

Answer (score 1):

Now, don't scowl at me.. You asked for the simplest solution :P

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String math = "12+3=15";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(.)(\\d+)=(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(math);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
        System.out.println(m.group(3));
        System.out.println(m.group(4));
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
12
+
3
15

EDIT : (\\d+)(.)(\\d+)=(\\d+) --> 
 \\d+ matches one or more digits.
 . matches anything
 () --> captures whatever is inside it
(\\d+)(.)(\\d+)=(\\d+) --> captures one or more digits followed by anything (+-* etc) then again one or more digits and ignores the "=" and then captures digits again.
```

captured groups are named from 1 to n.. group 0 represents the entire string.

Comment: Seems like a nice solution. I will try it. Can you please explain the line Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(.)(\\d+)=(\\d+)");
I want to learn what I am doing and why. Thank you

Comment: @vks yes it seem like an easier way. But operator can be either +,-,*,/

Comment: @user2939293 - edited my answer and explained it :P

Comment: Too bad, that you answer also accepts invalid strings like `"123=15"`.

Comment: @Tom - The OP said - *Yes, this is the only format I have* :P .. I could change it to `[+\\-*/]` .. But it won't make much of  a difference. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Well then let's hope he won't expand his program or read these equations from untrusted^ sources :P. (^ but your code won't cause any harm anyway :D)

Comment: @Tom - Or lets just hope that he *expands* his program to support `% ^ | &` etc :P

Answer (score 0):

```
\\b(\\d+)\\b|([+*\/-])
```

You can simply do this and grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/30

Or simply split by `\\b`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/31

```
var re = /\b(\d+)\b|([+=\\-])/gm;
var str = '12+3=15';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will read the links and try your solution. The operator can be either +,-,*,/

Comment: @vks - escape the `-` :P

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this regex in the content. How can I store num1 into variable int num1 and so on?
Thanks for your help

Comment: @vks - Ya.. right.. didn't read properly :P

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't java?